# Objects with conditional values

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to have several arguments passed to a function based on conditions.

The arguments are objects.

so basically I am trying to do this with booleans. If it's true add the arguments, if it's not add nothing.

```
theFunction(arg1, addArg2 && arg2, addArg3 && arg3);
```

This is not working.
What would be a way to achieve this?
Maybe I should build the list first but I don't know how to do this.

EDIT ---

I am using a library which can take as many arguments as needed
The arguments are as follows :

```
const style1 = props => ({
    borderRadius: "0%",
});

const style2 = props => ({
    width: "10px",
});

theFunction(style1, style2);
```

I want to pass those to theFunction based on values. To me, it seems like doing this with boolean is a good solution.
So sometimes I will call

```
theFunction(style1);
```

and sometimes

```
theFunction(style1, style2);
```

I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: please add some data for input and the wanted output.

Comment: You need a real [mcve]. What values do the variables have? What values do you expect `theFunction` to receive?

Comment: I think the question of OP is well stated. He wants to pass "nothing" (which probably should be "undefined" or "false", depending on his needs) if `addArg` is false and `arg` if `addArg` is true. No need to close this question.

Comment: Question updated. @le_m yes I want to pass something or nothing based on other values

Comment: There is no 'nothing' value you can pass to a function which prevents it from appearing in that function's argument list. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library function probably does not understand what passing `false` instead of an object as argument means. Unfortunately, there is no 'nothing' value you can pass to a function which prevents it from appearing in that function's argument list.

However, you can build an iterable argument list based on your needs and use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to pass it to your library function.

Example, assuming `f` is your library function:

```js
function f(...args) {
  console.log('Got', args);
}

var addArg2 = false, addArg3 = true;
var arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2, arg3 = 3;

// Not working:
f(arg1, addArg2 && arg2, addArg3 && arg3);

// Working:
var args = [arg1];
if (addArg2) args.push(arg2);
if (addArg3) args.push(arg3);
f(...args);
```

Comment: This is not working, as I would like. I do not control the function I am passing to. Maybe it can not handle this case ?

Comment: That is what I need for my case, that's clever. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.

```
// You can use the spread operator in the declaration to make 'arguments' an array
function theFunction(...args) {
    let obj = {};
    args.forEach( (item) => {
        // Using Object.entries() loop for the sake of legibility
        for( let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
            // For every object you pass in, assign to object to return
            obj[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Of course, if you're just merging all those objects together, you could use `Object.assign`

```
function theFunction(...args) {
    let obj = {};
    args.forEach( (item) => {
        Object.assign(obj, item);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

[More info on Object.assign() at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Good luck! Hope this helps out.

Comment: le_m answer was what I was looking for. Interesting answer though, it gives me ideas on what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

U can default value to null or w/e u like inside the function like

```
var a = arg || null;
```